# xamarin forms maps white screen in apk

Tags: xamarin, maps, xamarin.forms

I´m new in XF.

When i open my project emulating in my device (in debug or release mode) the map opens correctly and shows the pin in my phone.

I have never raised an apk but apparently i got.

But when i install the apk in my phone and start the application, the screen goes blank (like when I had not even put the key in the manifest)

I used the apk that was generated in a folder that i choose.

After, i tried to use the apk in C:\User[user]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Archives[folder date]*.apk, but an error occurred while trying to install.

Someone had this problem?

Thanks

Comment: did you sign your apk?

Comment: Have you followed this tutorial?
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/

Comment: how to sign? I did not want to publish on google play Mr. L

Comment: I will see Mario Galván

Comment: how can i get the key for release? The SHA-1 is unique in my computer